# binary conversion twos complement

Tags: binary, binary-operations

How to convert X which is a fractional (7.2) number from two's complement signed fractional to unsigned fractional.$X=011101110$ .I was thinking I should substract 1 and negate the bits but don't know if its right because I have a fractional part too. Also for conversion to signed magnitude I found it's 000010010 is it right?

Comment: How does $011101110$ encode $7.2$?

Comment: 7 denotes there are 7 bits for integer part and 2 for fractional 0111011.10

Comment: How is 0111011 equals 7?